# stop wordpress from resizing feature gif images

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

For one of site: bit.ly /2n3a53W
I am trying to add gif image as feature image, but wordpress is changing it to something like image-name-200x150.gif and using it.

How can I stop it from happening. 
I even tried replacing image-name-200x150.gif server with original gif but still its not working.

Comment: You need to change this inside the code of the template. Wordpress store the original size image and other size and there a function called to get the image and the parametre of this function specify the size. So you need to change it to always take the original size

Comment: @TemaniAfif Which file, can I modify for only .gif format?

Comment: no you can't for only one forma ... i cannot tell you wich file, you need to see the template used for the page whre you are trying to upload the featured image